# Class 'DecimalField' does not define '__sub__', so the '-' operator cannot be used on its instances

Tags: django

I am programming a property in Django which is supposed to gather its value from subtracting two models.DecimalField. Yet Pycharm is telling me that (see title).

How could it be that two decimals cannot be operated?

Example code

```
_profit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

amount_in_crypto = models.DecimalField(_('amount in Crypto'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=7)
crypto_market_price = models.DecimalField(_('Crypto market price'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
crypto_sell_price = models.DecimalField(_('Crypto sell price'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

@property
def profit(self):
    return (self.crypto_sell_price - self.crypto_market_price) * self.amount_in_crypto
profit.fget.short_description = _('profit')
```

Warning:
[image]

I have inspected Django DecimalField's code and indeed it does not define `__sub__` and it inherits from field (which wouldn't make any sense to implement that method), so warning seems correct but question is: Why doesn't Django implement mathematical operations in DecimalField? Is there a reason? Am I missing sth?

Comment: A field does not work with `__sub__`, but the meta-logic of a model will ensure that `self.crypto_sell_price` is *not* a `DecimalField`, but a `Decimal` itself. Pylint however does not fully "understands" the meta-logic. There is a pylint for Django that works better on this, although it still often make mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am programming a property in Django which is supposed to gather its value from subtracting two `models.DecimalField`.

**No**, you want to subtract two `Decimal` objects, not the fields that contain these.

While pylint is an effective tool, it can sometimes not understand the meta-logic, and especially not the one that Django has implemented. Pylint thus thinks that `self.crypto_sell_price` will be a `DecimalField`, but in reality it is a `Decimal` object.

You can work with [**`pylint-django`** [PyPi]](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/) instead, which can understand more of the logic that Django has implemented, although that tool can still fail to understand certain logic.